# Laravel validation code - view, model or controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am following a tutorial on Laravel 4 and the following validations are placed in the view

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('account-create-post') }}" method="post" >
<div class="field">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" {{ (Input::old('email')) ? 'value="' . e(input::old('email')) . ' " ' : ''}}>
    @if($errors->has('email'))
        {{ $errors->first('email') }}
    @endif  
</div>
```

It works, but seems to be counter to the MVC approach - should such validations be created in the model or controller?

Comment: First of all there is nothing validating in you view code. Second usually the validation is been done either on the controller or in a special validation class that you create .Third I don't think your code is valid, just use `value="{{ (Input::old('email')) }}"` nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Andre & Yannis - I understand, just wasn't expecting an "if" statement in the view, but the rules for the validation are indeed within the Controller - thanks for helping clarify!

Answer (score 1):

This code only displays validation errors, the actual validation takes place in the controller.